# Syntax Error While Calling DB2 Stored Procedure Through JMeter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, jmeter, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to call a DB2 Stored Procedure which has two Input parameters (Timestamp, both) and one Output parameter (Integer). I am trying to do so from JMeter JDBC Sampler and getting sql syntax exception.

```
Response code: 42884 -440
Response message: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=PROCEDURE;DEVSCHEMA.GET_ROW_COUNT, DRIVER=4.19.26

Response headers:
1272084586, URL=jdbc:db2://<db2IP>:<port>/DB2T, UserName=<someUserName>, IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
```

From IBM Documentation I got to know that this error happens when either Stored procedure is not present - which is not the case, Schema name incorrect - which is also not the case, mismatching number of parameters - I verified this but I am doubtful at this point because JMeter provides separate fields to be filled up and in one of the fields I might be passing incorrect value.

I have not much knowledge of JMeter but with the help from apache JMeter documentation I have set below values to the Sample Fields.

```
Query Type: Callable Statement 
Query: CALL DEVSCHEMA.GET_ROW_COUNT(?,?,?)
Parameter Values: ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,)},${__time(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,)},0 
Parameter Types: IN TIMESTAMP,IN TIMESTAMP,OUT INTEGER 
Variable Names:VARCOUNT 
Handle ResultSet: Store as a String
```

Can anyone please figure out where am I making a mistake? Many thanks.

Comment: My first guess at the cause would be the mixed-case schema name; try `DEVSCHEMA` instead of `devSchema`.

Comment: @mustaccio No that is just the any name I've put because actual schema name was too long and that is in Upper case only. Anyways I just edited question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It was literally something else about which I never gave a thought. When I got the same error when I tried to access the same SP using Java code, I contacted DB2 team who wrote the Stored procedure. And issue was with the SP. According to them `execute` access was given so after drilling here and there they preferred to create a new SP which worked without any issues. Else everything was perfect from JMeter side.